# Why is returning a cloned ndarray throwing an overflow error(exceeded max recursion limit)?

Tags: multidimensional-array, rust, rust-ndarray

I'm currently trying to write a function that is generally equivalent to [numpy's tile](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html). Currently each time I try to return a (altered or unaltered) clone of the input array, I get a warning about an overflow, and cargo prompts me to increase the recursion limit. however this function isn't recursive, so I'm assuming its happening somewhere in the implementation.

here is the stripped down function, ([full version](https://github.com/secretsauceai/mfcc-rust/blob/f462d3a035facffafa7f1537ac5d19650de934df/src/util.rs#L29)):

```rust
pub fn tile<A, D1, D2>(arr: &Array<A, D1>, reps: Vec<usize>) -> Array<A, D2>
where
    A: Clone,
    D1: Dimension,
    D2: Dimension,
{
    let num_of_reps = reps.len();

    //just clone the array if reps is all ones
    let mut res = arr.clone();
    let bail_flag = true;
    for &x in reps.iter() {
        if x != 1 {
            bail_flag = false;
        }
    }
    if bail_flag {
        let mut res_dim = res.shape().to_owned();
        _new_shape(num_of_reps, res.ndim(), &mut res_dim);
        res.to_shape(res_dim);
        return res;
    }
    ...
    //otherwise do extra work
    ...
    return res.reshape(shape_out);
}
```

this is the actual error I'm getting on returning res:

```
overflow evaluating the requirement `&ArrayBase<_, _>: Neg`
consider increasing the recursion limit by adding a `#![recursion_limit = "1024"]` attribute to your crate (`mfcc_2`)
required because of the requirements on the impl of `Neg` for `&ArrayBase<_, _>`
511 redundant requirements hidden
required because of the requirements on the impl of `Neg` for `&ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<A>, D1>`rustcE0275
```

I looked at the [implementation of Neg in ndarray](https://github.com/rust-ndarray/ndarray/blob/ce3f541f8778749708059d52289c1dee853606a3/src/impl_ops.rs#L370), it doesn't seem to be recursive, so I'm a little confused as to what is going on.

p.s. I'm aware there are other errors in this code, as those appeared after I switched from `A` to f64(the actual type I plan on using the function with), but those are *mostly* trivial to fix. Still if you have suggestions on any error you see I appreciate them nonetheless.

Comment: The overflow isn't in the function. The overflow happens in the compiler when it is trying to resolve the type of your array. Remember getting the same error, not sure what was the solution

Comment: The actual error is with your return type. You are returning an `Array<A, D1>` while the return type is `Array<A, D2>`. Why do you need two dimension generic arguments? Using only one would solve the compile error

Comment: @susitsm, is there a way to type it so that D1 and D2 may or may not be the same dimensions(without using `IxDyn`). following the original functions behavior, the dimensions of the output array is `max(input_dim, len_of_reps)`.

Comment: Sorry but I cannot reproduce your error. Pasting your full code into the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=26230bd74e67937e830cdfffeeae9204) produces many errors, but not the one your describe. Trying to compile the slimmed-down version doesn't help. I also don't see any use of the `Neg` operator on an array (though it could be in a constraint and not in the code directly). *"I'm aware there are other errors in this code ... but those are mostly trivial to fix"*. If they are trivial to fix, then fix them. Don't make us struggle to help you.

Comment: Not without using `IxDyn`. The type system is not capable of `max`. Maybe in the very very far future with a lot more `const generic` support something like `fn tile(arr: Array<A, D1>, res: [usize; D2]) -> Array<A, cmp::max(D1, D2)>` will be possible. Until then `IxDyn` is the way

Comment: I'm kind of curious, if both `D1` and `D2` are instances of `Dimension`, why can't `D1==D2`?

Comment: They can, but why they are both present if that's the case?

Comment: @Cerberus it's mainly because of how the function behaves. it's in my previous comment, but the dimensions of the output will either be exactly the same as the original(as will the actual returned array) or will have a number of dimensions equal to the length of the number of reps

Comment: @susitism, honestly because until I fix this one, or change the code to be less generic, I'm sort of flying blind. This project started as a port of ton of python code, and my group has just been playing whack-a-mole with errors. I could make this function less generic, tailored to how it's being called in the code, but I was hoping to wrap pad(after I make it work for higher dimensions) and tile in a crate, or contribute them to one of the ndarray helper crates.